# Does the worker process restart if I replace a Dll on my website on IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5

Does the worker process restart if I replace a Dll on my website on IIS 7.5

For example while deploying my application I just copy paste stuff and do not restart the website or stop it would be worker process restart for the App Pool under

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could actually replace the DLL, it means it was not loaded by the worker process at the time (or else, the .dll file would be locked). Seeing as it hasn't been used yet, the worker process will not restart - it will just load the new .dll file if/when it's needed.

However, I do not recommend "warm" upgrades like these since it leaves you in an undetermined state.

Comment: I think we got into this issue currently one of our new Dev just deployed a build by replacing now we are getting some weird errors on the app. Specifically with Ajax call are returning Whole pages instead of Json Object , Just wanted to know could this trigger such an Issue ?

Comment: NEVER replace a key part of your system while the server is still running - it could lead to inconsistent results within users and even withing same-session. Just restart the server and see if the bad behavior is solved. If not, you have a bug somewhere. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. 
The process worker will restart for several other reasons also:

Web.config modification
Changing or adding any file to the /bin directory

It´s recommended that you stop the application pool and your web site, make any change, and then start it again, so you don't have weird behaviour on your app.